# Remove duplicate rows in a Matrix in R

Tags: r, duplicates, igraph, network-analysis

So I'm trying to do a networkanalysis with igraph in R, but I'm a R newbie.
My Excel database looks like this.. just bigger.
[image: Excel database]

```
test<-separate(ID_test, 'Contacts 1', paste("Contacts", 1:20, sep="_"), sep=",", extra="drop")
m <- as.matrix(test)
el <- cbind(m[, 1], c(m[, -1]))
el2<-na.omit(el)
testel<- graph_from_edgelist(el2, directed=FALSE)
plot(testel)
```

I sepArated the data from Contacts to multiple columns and transformed the data to a matrix so I can create an edgelist with cbind.
After that I deleted every row where an NA is present.
With igraph I could then plot my undirected network.

The Problem is that I have duplicate rows where the IDs are just switched between V1 and V2.
Therefore I have f.e. ID_009 and ID003 twice in my network cause the edgelist looks like this..

[image: edgelist]

As you can see the first and the last row are basically the same just with switched values between V1 and V2.

I already tried multiple solutions but none seems to work for me.

```
el4<-el3[!duplicated(el[c("V1", "V2")]),] #doesnt recognize the right duplicates as in the example above
el4<-el3[!duplicated(paste(pmin(V1, V2), pmax(V1, V2)))] #Error in pmin(V1, V2) : object 'V1' not found
el4<-el3[!duplicated(paste(pmin("V1", "V2")), pmax("V1", "V2"))] # creates values with which i cant create an network
g <- graph_from_edgelist(unique(rbind(el2[, 1:2])), directed = FALSE) #doesnt change anything
plot(g)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, MemeBeauftragter! (1) Sample data would be really useful here, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for the discussions on `dput`, `data.frame`, and `read.table` to provide unambiguous representative sample (not big) data. (2) Please don't include just images of data, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). (3) From the images of data, it appears that some strings might have embedded spaces, e.g., `"ID_009"` (no-space) vs `"ID_001 "` (trailing space), this would defeat `duplicated`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you very much! The trailing spaces were the problem. I trimmed my data frame and with the solution below i could eliminate the duplicates. For further problems im also gonna pay attention to your comments about providing better information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example on how to remove duplicate rows in any order:

```r
el <- data.frame(V1 = paste0("id_00", c(3,rep(4,8), rep(9,3))), 
                 V2 = paste0("id_00", c(9,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3)))

el
#>        V1     V2
#> 1  id_003 id_009
#> 2  id_004 id_001
#> 3  id_004 id_002
#> 4  id_004 id_003
#> 5  id_004 id_005
#> 6  id_004 id_006
#> 7  id_004 id_007
#> 8  id_004 id_008
#> 9  id_004 id_009
#> 10 id_009 id_001
#> 11 id_009 id_002
#> 12 id_009 id_003
dups <- duplicated(t(apply(el, 1, sort)))

el[!dups, ]
#>        V1     V2
#> 1  id_003 id_009
#> 2  id_004 id_001
#> 3  id_004 id_002
#> 4  id_004 id_003
#> 5  id_004 id_005
#> 6  id_004 id_006
#> 7  id_004 id_007
#> 8  id_004 id_008
#> 9  id_004 id_009
#> 10 id_009 id_001
#> 11 id_009 id_002
```

Comment: You can also use `duplicated(apply(el, 1, sort), MARGIN=2)`
`

Comment: Thank you very much. After trimming my data frame from whitespaces your solution worked out!